# Render image is zoomed in and doesn't match the camera view

Tags: rendering, image

When I start rendering my images you see that the render is zoomed in, I don't know why this happened cause I never touched the camera or something?

[image: First image: Render]
[image: Second image: Camera view]

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe you've keyframed the camera, or rendered a border with Alt B? If this is not the problem please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=0NqD3yAK" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/0NqD3yAK/) @moonboots

Answer (score 0):

You have an image called *0000.jpg* in the *Video Sequencer* (it's hard to see it because it can be hidden behind a bar if it's too vertically thin, zoom to see it), as long as it will be there it will be rendered, so remove it or disable the *Pipeline > Sequencer* option in the *Output panel > Post Processing*:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU MY BRODDA!!